# Notification access for android app from SDK

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-firmware

How can I grant permission to access notifications to my caandorid application (system app) automatically from android sdk?
The android system should not prompt to ask for grating access.

Comment: Staring at Android 23, you're required to ask  runtime permissions

Comment: From linux system side is there any possible way by which I can give permissions automatically?

Comment: @cricket_007 
 
I am developing a system/priv-app/ application for custom hardware, but don't have access to the notifications. I have to explicitly grant permission for it, how can I grant permission by default? Anywhere from android firmware?